# Laravel get single record from relationship for each part

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two table parts and images. Each part has multiple images. I would like to display all the parts with their images but I only want to display single image. So if a part has multiple images I would like to display one image. Here is my query

```
return Part::with(['images'=> function($q)
{
   $q->limit(1);
}])->get();
```

The above query only displays one image. But i would like to display one image for each part.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your issue, you're retrieving one image but you want a image by part?.

Comment: Shoudln't your model be `Part` instead of `Parts`?

Comment: Yes my model is Part. had a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible with "with", as its act like below:

```
select * from parts

select * from images where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) limit 1
```

Instead you can do this in a loop like below:

```
foreach ( Parts::get() as $Part ) {
    $FirstImageOfPart = $Part->images()->first();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Moein Porkamel. It worked! I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution in Laravel.